# What are these Device Object Characteristics / Flags in Windows 10 ntoskrnl!IopParseDevice

Tags: disassembly, windows, kernel

In Windows 10 looking at **ntoskrnl!IopParseDevice** I'm trying to work out the name / purpose of the flags in this check, which seem to be testing for values in a [DEVICE_OBJECT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ns-wdm-_device_object?msclkid=2d5d8b95c5b411ec885d6080ba6e9290) Characteristics property and the flags property. In particular checking for device object characteristics **40001h** and flags **600100h**

What what I can tell the 0x40000 device characteristic and flags adding up to 0x600000h aren't defined in the Windows Driver kit.

The section of code is:

```
    PAGE:00000001404197CC                                                 ; 825:     Characteristics = DEVICE_OBJECT->Characteristics;
PAGE:00000001404197CC
PAGE:00000001404197CC                                                 loc_1404197CC:                          ; CODE XREF: IopParseDevice+CFD↑j
PAGE:00000001404197CC                                                                                         ; IopParseDevice+D17↑j ...
PAGE:00000001404197CC 8B 4E 34                                                        mov     ecx, [rsi+34h]
PAGE:00000001404197CF                                                 ; 826:     if ( (Characteristics & 0x40001) == 0 || (DEVICE_OBJECT->Flags & 0x600100) != 0 )
PAGE:00000001404197CF F7 C1 01 00 04 00                                               test    ecx, 40001h
PAGE:00000001404197D5 74 64                                                           jz      short loc_14041983B
PAGE:00000001404197D7 F7 46 30 00 01 60 00                                            test    dword ptr [rsi+30h], 600100h
PAGE:00000001404197DE 75 5B                                                           jnz     short loc_14041983B
PAGE:00000001404197E0                                                 ; 832:       v114 = (struct _SECURITY_SUBJECT_CONTEXT *)a3;
PAGE:00000001404197E0 48 8B 7C 24 58                                                  mov     rdi, [rsp+208h+AccessState]
PAGE:00000001404197E5                                                 ; 833:       if ( (Characteristics & 0x100) == 0 )
PAGE:00000001404197E5 0F BA E1 08                                                     bt      ecx, 8
PAGE:00000001404197E9 72 55                                                           jb      short loc_140419840
PAGE:00000001404197EB                                                 ; 835:         v215[0] = 0;
PAGE:00000001404197EB C6 44 24 60 00                                                  mov     [rsp+208h+var_1A8], 0
PAGE:00000001404197F0                                                 ; 836:         SeIsAppContainerOrIdentifyLevelContext(a3 + 32, v215);
PAGE:00000001404197F0 48 8D 4F 20                                                     lea     rcx, [rdi+20h]
PAGE:00000001404197F4 48 8D 54 24 60                                                  lea     rdx, [rsp+208h+var_1A8]
PAGE:00000001404197F9 E8 62 C8 07 00                                                  call    SeIsAppContainerOrIdentifyLevelContext
```

When stepping through via a Kernel debugger, on calling nt!NtQueryFullAttributesFile with object attributes pointing to path "??\C:" the value being checked with test ecx instruction is set to 0x00060000. The value for test    dword ptr [rsi+30h] (flags) differs depending on what drive I select. For ??\C:\ this is set to **0x1150** and for ??\E:\ it is set to **0x3050.**

In wdm.h  from Windows DDK can see the following definitions:

```
//
// Define the various device characteristics flags
//

#define FILE_REMOVABLE_MEDIA                        0x00000001
#define FILE_READ_ONLY_DEVICE                       0x00000002
#define FILE_FLOPPY_DISKETTE                        0x00000004
#define FILE_WRITE_ONCE_MEDIA                       0x00000008
#define FILE_REMOTE_DEVICE                          0x00000010
#define FILE_DEVICE_IS_MOUNTED                      0x00000020
#define FILE_VIRTUAL_VOLUME                         0x00000040
#define FILE_AUTOGENERATED_DEVICE_NAME              0x00000080
#define FILE_DEVICE_SECURE_OPEN                     0x00000100
#define FILE_CHARACTERISTIC_PNP_DEVICE              0x00000800
#define FILE_CHARACTERISTIC_TS_DEVICE               0x00001000
#define FILE_CHARACTERISTIC_WEBDAV_DEVICE           0x00002000
#define FILE_CHARACTERISTIC_CSV                     0x00010000
#define FILE_DEVICE_ALLOW_APPCONTAINER_TRAVERSAL    0x00020000
#define FILE_PORTABLE_DEVICE                        0x00040000
#define FILE_REMOTE_DEVICE_VSMB                     0x00080000
#define FILE_DEVICE_REQUIRE_SECURITY_CHECK          0x00100000

// Define Device Object (DO) flags
    //
    // DO_DAX_VOLUME - If set, this is a DAX volume i.e. the volume supports mapping a file directly
    // on the persistent memory device.  The cached and memory mapped IO to user files wouldn't
    // generate paging IO.
    //
    #define DO_VERIFY_VOLUME                    0x00000002      
    #define DO_BUFFERED_IO                      0x00000004      
    #define DO_EXCLUSIVE                        0x00000008      
    #define DO_DIRECT_IO                        0x00000010      
    #define DO_MAP_IO_BUFFER                    0x00000020      
    #define DO_DEVICE_INITIALIZING              0x00000080      
    #define DO_SHUTDOWN_REGISTERED              0x00000800      
    #define DO_BUS_ENUMERATED_DEVICE            0x00001000      
    #define DO_POWER_PAGABLE                    0x00002000      
    #define DO_POWER_INRUSH                     0x00004000      
    #define DO_DEVICE_TO_BE_RESET               0x04000000      
    #define DO_DAX_VOLUME                       0x10000000
```

Comment: Would be good if you could give either a hash (or the PDB identifier) or a _full_ version number of the ntoskrnl.exe you're looking at, so others can follow along.

Comment: In general, I think it's good advice to keep older DDKs and latest WDKs handy and have a good and fast text search tool to look for these items. Adding the ReactOS code into the mix is certainly a good idea, but results from it should be taken with a pinch of salt. What also often works are code searches for those _symbolic names_ you know to find adjacent ones you don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, not sure which WDK you were using, but at least the `Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\km\ntifs.h` and `Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\km\ntddk.h` of the newest (non-preview/beta) WDK list:

```
#define DO_VERIFY_VOLUME                    0x00000002
#define DO_BUFFERED_IO                      0x00000004
#define DO_EXCLUSIVE                        0x00000008
#define DO_DIRECT_IO                        0x00000010
#define DO_MAP_IO_BUFFER                    0x00000020
#define DO_DEVICE_HAS_NAME                  0x00000040 // *
#define DO_DEVICE_INITIALIZING              0x00000080
#define DO_SYSTEM_BOOT_PARTITION            0x00000100 // *
#define DO_LONG_TERM_REQUESTS               0x00000200 // *
#define DO_NEVER_LAST_DEVICE                0x00000400 // *
#define DO_SHUTDOWN_REGISTERED              0x00000800
#define DO_BUS_ENUMERATED_DEVICE            0x00001000
#define DO_POWER_PAGABLE                    0x00002000
#define DO_POWER_INRUSH                     0x00004000
#define DO_LOW_PRIORITY_FILESYSTEM          0x00010000 // *
#define DO_SUPPORTS_PERSISTENT_ACLS         0x00020000 // * <- only in ntifs.h
#define DO_SUPPORTS_TRANSACTIONS            0x00040000 // *
#define DO_FORCE_NEITHER_IO                 0x00080000 // *
#define DO_VOLUME_DEVICE_OBJECT             0x00100000 // *
#define DO_SYSTEM_SYSTEM_PARTITION          0x00200000 // *
#define DO_SYSTEM_CRITICAL_PARTITION        0x00400000 // *
#define DO_DISALLOW_EXECUTE                 0x00800000 // *
#define DO_DEVICE_TO_BE_RESET               0x04000000
#define DO_DEVICE_IRP_REQUIRES_EXTENSION    0x08000000 // *
#define DO_DAX_VOLUME                       0x10000000
#define DO_BOOT_CRITICAL                    0x20000000
```

Those marked with `*` are not on the list you gave. But I think this list is comprehensive enough to decode *almost* (except for 0x01) all items you were looking for:

- 0x40001 == `DO_SUPPORTS_TRANSACTIONS | 0x01`
- 0x600100 == `DO_SYSTEM_BOOT_PARTITION | DO_SYSTEM_SYSTEM_PARTITION | DO_SYSTEM_CRITICAL_PARTITION`

I was, however, at first also unable to find what the 0x01 flag means. However, **if** ReactOS is to be trusted ([and often it can be trusted in those matters](https://github.com/reactos/reactos/blob/master/media/doc/notes#L43), but not always) [this could be](https://github.com/reactos/reactos/blob/999345a4feaae1e74533c96fa2cdfa1bce50ec5f/sdk/include/xdk/iotypes.h#L245):

```
#define DO_UNLOAD_PENDING               0x00000001
```